# SQLAlchemy MYSQL query utf8 character problem

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Trying to query all items from a mysql (charset:utf8) table which has a field that contains rows with chinese and other special characters I am taking the above error

```
items = session.query(Item).all()
```

> File
> "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-WesSANjA/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
> line 355, in _post_get_result self._rows = self._fetch_row(0) File
> "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/server-WesSANjA/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py",
> line 328, in _fetch_row return self._result.fetch_row(size,
> self._fetch_type) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/encodings/cp1252.py",
> line 15, in decode return
> codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 30: character maps to

Comment: Did you append `?charset=utf8mb4` to your connection URI as suggested [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection)?

Comment: @GordThompson yes just right now it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection), we need to use `?charset=utf8mb4` for full Unicode support (including emoji):

```py
e = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?charset=utf8mb4")
```